# Add header in URL HTML

Tags: html

Hi I am trying to add a header in URL

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">GoTo</a>
```

also I want to add X-forwarded-for in header with value as "ABC" in my above URL, how can I do so

Comment: you could use the tag title

Comment: could you please give me an example

Comment: if you wanna add header you can do it by adding `<h1>My Header Title<h1> <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">GoTo</a> your html` I mentioned the `title` because I thought in the tab title in the begging